# iPhone App crashing - viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

My iphone app crashes when I add a method to the viewDidLoad in my main viewcontroller:

```
#import "dbQuestionGetterViewController.h"
#import "dbConnector.h";

@implementation dbQuestionGetterViewController
@synthesize questions;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    //code to initialise view
    NSDictionary* arr = [dbConnector getQuestions:2 from:@"http://dev.speechlink.co.uk/David/get_questions.php"];
    questions = arr;
    [arr release];  
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I'm calling a static method from the dbConnector class, but it crashes before even loading..

The method in dbConnector:

```
//method to 
+(NSDictionary*)getQuestions:(NSInteger)sectionId from: (NSString*) url{
    //connect to database given by url
    //NSError        *error = nil;
    //NSURLResponse  *response = nil;
    NSMutableString* myRequestString = [[NSMutableString string]initWithFormat:@"section=%@", sectionId];
    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]]; 
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    //post section 
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];

    //store them in the dictionary
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *questions = [json objectFromJSONString];
    [json release];

    [request release];
    return [questions autorelease];
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You got that code from the answer I left in your other question.  Please accept it if it helped you.  I spent quite a while on that. :/

Comment: You doing lots of things wrong. Put the [super viewDidLoad] call at the top of your method for a starters. You are also passing an autoreleased object back to your method, assigning it to another variable and then releasing it. When you do `questions = arr`, `[arr release]`, your questions object is pointing to the same memory location which is now garbage. Also have a look at your `myRequestString` initialisation, you're not init'ing it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're not doing anything with this code:

```
NSMutableString* myRequestString = [[NSMutableString string]initWithFormat:@"section=%@", sectionId];
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]]; 
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
//post section 
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
```

Remove it.

Secondly,  `questions` is already autoreleased.

```
NSDictionary *questions = [json objectFromJSONString]; // < autoreleased
```

So simply doing `return questions;` should work.

This also means that you should **not** under any case release this returned value.  Thus, get rid of this:

```
[arr release];
```

Comment: The first few lines are what I use to post data to a database. The program still crashes after making your changes...

Comment: Did you ignore what I said later in the answer?  That is your problem.

Comment: Please copy/paste what you have right now after making the changes.  Put it on http://www.pastebin.com

Comment: It would have helped if you had given a link.  Here it is: http://pastebin.com/Tj1cGCAz  Please put that link in your original post as an edit so others can see the complete implementation and help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are releasing the `arr` object that `getQuestions` returns.  Since you've already marked this object as `autorelease` you don't need to explicitly release it yourself.  Remove the following line from `viewDidLoad` and you should be set:

```
[arr release];
```

Also, your `myRequestString` is suspect.  You are calling the `string` class method, which returns a fully allocated and initialized string, but then you're calling `initWithFormat` on it, which is normally for strings you've just `alloc`-ed.  Replace that line with:

```
[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@"section=%@", sectionId]
```

and then release it right after your `[request release]`.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: forgive my ignorance but how do i do that :S

Comment: It should appear in the debugger window after the crash.

Answer (score 1):

The NSDictionary that is returned from the static method is autoreleased. But you release it in the viewDidLoad method.